# Aliasing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this query in Oracle and want to compile it as well on SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    HOLDER_CODE, CALCULATED_AMOUNT
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         DA.HOLDER_CODE, 
         ROUND(FAB.AMOUNT * FCE.EXCHANGE_RATE,0) AS CALCULATED_AMOUNT, 
         FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID as FAB_DATE,
         MAX(FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DA.HOLDER_CODE) as MAX_DATE_BALANCE
     FROM 
         DIM_ACCOUNT DA 
     JOIN 
         FACT_AS_BALANCE FAB ON FAB.ACCOUNT_ID  = DA.ID
     JOIN 
         DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS DAC ON DAC.ID = FAB.BALANCE_TYPE_ID
     LEFT JOIN 
         FACT_CURRENCY_EXCHANGE FCE ON FCE.FROM_CURRENCY_ID = FAB.CURRENCY_ID
     WHERE 
         DAC.BALANCE_CLOSING_FLAG = 'Y' 
         AND TO_CURRENCY_ID = (SELECT DC.ID  
                               FROM DIM_CURRENCY DC
                               WHERE DC.IS_DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'Y')
         AND FAB.AMOUNT > 0)
WHERE 
    FAB_DATE = MAX_DATE_BALANCE
ORDER BY 
    CALCULATED_AMOUNT DESC;
```

But when I run it I get the following exception:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. SQLState:  S0001
>   ErrorCode: 156

So I guess, it's the last where clause, which indicates this. What is wrong and what should it be?

Comment: Just give a alias to  your big sub query select distinct ... from ( ... ) as K where K.FAB_DATE ...

Answer (score 11):

You just need to alias the *subquery*

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOLDER_CODE, CALCULATED_AMOUNT
FROM (
  SELECT DA.HOLDER_CODE, 
         //// snip subquery
    AND FAB.AMOUNT > 0
 ) alias_name_here //<--- here
WHERE FAB_DATE = MAX_DATE_BALANCE
ORDER BY CALCULATED_AMOUNT DESC;
```

You can use `as alias_name_here` or just `alias_name_here` - SQL Server allows either syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you **must** give a name at your "table"
i give is with "**as T**"

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOLDER_CODE, CALCULATED_AMOUNT
FROM (
  SELECT DA.HOLDER_CODE, 
         ROUND(FAB.AMOUNT * FCE.EXCHANGE_RATE,0) AS CALCULATED_AMOUNT, 
         FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID as FAB_DATE,
         MAX(FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DA.HOLDER_CODE) as MAX_DATE_BALANCE
  FROM DIM_ACCOUNT DA 
        JOIN FACT_AS_BALANCE FAB ON FAB.ACCOUNT_ID  = DA.ID
        JOIN DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS DAC ON DAC.ID = FAB.BALANCE_TYPE_ID
        LEFT JOIN FACT_CURRENCY_EXCHANGE FCE ON FCE.FROM_CURRENCY_ID = FAB.CURRENCY_ID
  WHERE DAC.BALANCE_CLOSING_FLAG = 'Y' 
  AND TO_CURRENCY_ID = ( 
SELECT DC.ID FROM DIM_CURRENCY DC
WHERE DC.IS_DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'Y')
    AND FAB.AMOUNT > 0
 ) as T
WHERE FAB_DATE = MAX_DATE_BALANCE
ORDER BY CALCULATED_AMOUNT DESC;
```